# Microsoft.Scripting.ArgumentTypeException: expected Fill, got Fill

Tags: .net, ironpython, zedgraph

I'm currently writing a GUI program using winform with zedgraph library in ironpython, and I got two problems.

1. I tried to change the background color of my graph GUI, using

   ```
       # Color Fills

   self.my_pane.Fill = Fill(Color.Black)
   self.my_pane.Chart.Fill = Fill(Color.Black)
   ```

   but it turns out, it gives me an error

   Microsoft.Scripting.ArgumentTypeException: expected Fill, got Fill

   but, I have checked the [documentation](http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/documentation/html/P_ZedGraph_PaneBase_Fill.htm), the type is correct.
2. When I comment out the above code, and keep running the program, I got another error for the following code

   ```
       self.point_list = RollingPointPairList(self.rpl_cap)
       my_curve = self.my_pane.AddCurve("Curve", self.point_list, Color.Yellow, SymbolType.None)
   ```

   this time it says, expeted a IPointList type, got RollingPointPairList, but RollingPointPairList is a subclass of IPointList. Documentation [here for method](http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/documentation/html/M_ZedGraph_GraphPane_AddCurve_3.htm) and [here for type](http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/documentation/html/T_ZedGraph_RollingPointPairList.htm)

I'm wondering weather if I did something wrong, since when I use the same code to run another GUI program, it works. In both of the program I use

```
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.EnableVisualStyles()
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(self.graph)
```

to start my winform GUI

Does anyone have some idea of what's going on here?

Thanks !

**Solution:**

**So, I created a whole new file, and copy pasted the code line by line, 
and then it works ... but the origin file still doen't work, I'm confused ..**

**Update**

**Ok, it's something wrong with my import, I have add a sys path after import zedGraph module, so, After I move the import after adding sys.path, it works. And the reason why create a new file works is because I import both old and new file when I use it, so it acutally import the zedGarph module**